# How do I fix the maximum depth exceeded error when sorting the table using useSortBy

Tags: reactjs, react-table

My code

```
import React from "react";
import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";
import "../App.css";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import * as BsIcons from "react-icons/bs";

function Applicants() {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      dateSubmitted: "2022-04-22",
      position: "Developer",
      status: "HR Interview",
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Smith",
      dateSubmitted: "2022-04-20",
      position: "Designer",
      status: "Job Offer",
    },
    // Add more data here
  ];

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name", accessor: "name", 
      },
      {
        Header: "Date Submitted", accessor: "dateSubmitted",
      },
      {
        Header: "Position", accessor: "position",
      },
      {
        Header: "Status", accessor: "status",
        Cell: (row) => {
          let borderColor, textColor;
          switch (row.value) {
            case "Pre-screening":
              borderColor = "blue";
              textColor = "blue";
              break;
            case "HR Interview":
            case "Technical interview":
              borderColor = "green";
              textColor = "green";
              break;
            case "Final Interview":
              borderColor = "yellow";
              textColor = "yellow";
              break;
            case "Job Offer":
            case "Accepted job offer":
              borderColor = "red";
              textColor = "red";
              break;
            default:
              borderColor = "black";
              textColor = "inherit";
          }

          return (
            <button
              style={{
                border: `2px solid ${borderColor}`,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                color: textColor,
                cursor: "pointer",
                padding: "0.5rem",
                paddingInlineEnd: "20%",
                paddingInlineStart: "20%",
                borderRadius: "0.4rem"
              }}
            >
              {row.value}
            </button>
          );
        }
        
      },
      {
        Header: "Actions", accessor: "actions",
        Cell: (row) => (
          <div>
            <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}><AiIcons.AiOutlineSearch size={30} /></span>
            <span style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: "10px" }}><BsIcons.BsTrashFill size={25}/></span>
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,

  } = useTable({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  return (
    <div className="applicants">
      <h1>Applicants</h1>
      <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ margin: "auto", width: "69%", height: "auto", overflow: "scroll", textAlign: "center" }}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                 <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                 {column.render('Header')}
                 {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                 <span>
                   {column.isSorted
                     ? column.isSortedDesc
                       ? ' '
                       : ' '
                     : ''}
                 </span>
               </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                  <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );

        }
export default Applicants;
```

Ideally when I click the header the table should be sorted but instead it just returns this error
Unhandled Thrown Error!
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.